# SQL SELECT column value based on value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgresql. I would like to write a SELECT statement with a column value based on the value in the database.

For example.

```
|  id  |  indicator  |
|   1  |       0     |
|   2  |       1     |
```

indicator can be 0 or 1 only where 0 = manual and 1 = auto.

Expected output from a SELECT *

```
1 manual
2 auto
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select id, case indicator
             when 0 then 'manual'
             when 1 then 'auto'
           end as indicator
from the_table;
```

If you need that frequently you could create a view for that.

In the long run, it might be better to create a proper lookup table and join to that:

```
create table indicator
(
  id integer primary key, 
  name text not null
);
insert into indicator (id, name)
values (0, 'manua', 1, 'auto');

alter table the_table 
   add constraint fk_indicator 
   foreign key (indicator) references indicator (id);
```

Then join to it:

```
select t.id, i.name as indicator
from the_table t
  join indicator i on i.id = t.indicator;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works (I just have to wait 10 min to mark as the answer)